# Cannot get simplexml content inside a function

Tags: php

I got strange problem, when i doing echo $setting->samp->url; it works perfectly but when i put it inside a function. It show me Notice undefined variable, what happened here??

```
$setting = simplexml_load_file('setting.xml');
#Content inside <samp><url>value</url></samp> printed.
echo $setting->samp->url;
sampserver_update();
#Problem
function sampserver_update() {
    echo $setting->samp->url;
}
```

Comment: You don't have access to your `$setting` variable inside your function

Comment: if your problem solved, then please mark the answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because $setting is not available inside the function. You might want to pass it as an argument.

Read about variable scopes here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1):

Value must be passed as argument to function

```
sampserver_update($setting);
function sampserver_update($setting) {
    echo $setting->samp->url;
}
```

just replace this lines

Comment: Yes this is worked as the other answer but the other answer have a bit good explaination because it give me link in to the php documentation, thanks for help by the way, i really appreciate that !!.

Comment: ya I didn't explain, I thought "pass as argument to function" would be enough..anyway thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Update your function to following

```
function sampserver_update()
{
    $setting = simplexml_load_file('setting.xml');
    return $setting->samp->url;
}
```

Calling and print

```
echo sampserver_update();
```